# How can I use GETDATE() to get month and year from the past month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I get it to one statement that can get me 
last month and this year?

I have a INSERT INTO and in a column report_date [datetime]

```
insert into table_a (report_date) values ( ??);
```

i want to show this past month and year,
So for example today is 4/21/2014 
so it would show 3/2014 in the column 
If today was MAY 1 2014 , it would show 4/2014?
Is this possible or does it have to have a day?

Comment: past month or last month?

Comment: to get the past month of this year, to output the year and the month wiht the same statement

Comment: in other words to get this year last month, for example to get 3/2014

Comment: If you want the result as a DateTime value, you must have a day involved - do you want the first, the last day, or the same day as the current day but one month earlier?

Comment: Oh i didnt know i would have to have a day involved. Because it would cause problems in like in a month that doesnt have 30/31 days. so it would not be possible to have a select get me '3/2014', i would have to separate them to get last month and this year?

Comment: What data type are you looking for, just a string like `'3/2014'`?

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: You could just use `DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())` as Dave and Zak suggested below, and set a custom format to show the date without the day. As for month ends, it's clever enough to get the month right, e.g. `SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '2014-mar-31')` gives `February, 28 2014 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get 'last month' with 'this year' you could do:

```
SELECT CAST(
  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
  CAST(MONTH(GETDATE())-1 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
  CAST(DAY(GETDATE())  AS VARCHAR)
AS DATETIME)
```

But then in JAN 2015, it would return DEC 2015.
If you just want last month, use the 'DATEADD' function.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```